# Getting Eclipse to recognise symbols defined in a Makefile

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, makefile

I have a GCC Makefile project in Eclipse with a symbol defined in the Makefile:

`GLOBAL_DEFINES += MY_SYMBOL=1`

How do I get Eclipse to parse the Makefile so that I don't get the annoying error in the editor:

> Symbol 'MY_SYMBOL' could not be resolved

(There's nothing wrong with the build, by the way, this is just for visualisation).

Comment: IMO You need to write the Eclipse plugin which parses the makefiles and integrates it with the indexer.

Comment: Ain't nobody got time for that!

Comment: So you will have to live without it :)

Comment: Which kind of definition is understood by your Eclipse setup? `.h` files? Text? You can write a text file from GNUmake with `$(file > myfile.h,\#define MY_SYMBOL 1)` for example.

Comment: I don't know what Eclipse understands at the moment, but the symbols are defined in the Makefile itself. Any symbols in .h or .c files are all discovered by the indexer.